# React.js: Passing certain props to children components upon routing to parent container

Tags: javascript, reactjs, share, parent-child, react-router

Basically my question surrounds the best practices of the relationship between parent and children components, and how to render a child component with specific props from the route alone, for sharing URL links (like sharing something on Facebook).

For example:

My parent component is the *Photos* container and it is responsible for rendering a *PhotoFeed* component (which in turn renders *PhotoFeedItem* components).

I have a simple route like this:

```
<Route path="photos" component={Photos} onEnter = {onPageEnter}/>
```

This will render the "Photos" section which renders the *PhotoFeed* upon arrival. When a user clicks on a *PhotoFeedItem*,the *PhotoDetails* component renders which is basically a modal with the expanded image, and more details about the photo like comments, tags, etc. All of this functionality has already been developed, and I have it all working properly when the user lands on the "Photos" section.

My component structure can be summarized like this:

```
<Photos>

  <PhotoFeed>
    <PhotoFeedItem onClick={this.expandPhoto}/> * n
  </PhotoFeed>

  {this.state.expanded ? <PhotoDetails data={this.state.photoToExpand}/>

</Photos>
```

The state test checks if the user has clicked on a *PhotoFeedItem*, and if so, renders the expanded *PhotoDetails* modal with more detailed data about the photo.

My main question is if there are any best practices in terms of rendering a specific Child component based on the route. Is it as simple as creating a Route like this:

```
<Route path="photos" onEnter = {onPageEnter}>
    <IndexRoute component={Photos} onEnter = {onPageEnter}/>
    <Route path=":photoId" component={PhotoDetails}/>
</Route>
```

Therefore the shareable URL would be something like www.myapp.com/photos/12, thus launching the *PhotoDetails* modal that has the id 12 in our database (or something like that)?

**I guess my question comes down to these thoughts / concerns:**

So far I have the *Photos* parent component fetching and passing all the data to its children. Depending on which *FeedItem* a user clicks, it will properly launch the expanded modal with more detailed data. Now.... If I want to achieve shareable URLs, how should I populate the *PhotoDetails* component with data? Should my *PhotoDetails* modal recieve data from its parent (*Photos.js*) or should it look at the URL and use that to determine which ID / endpoint to fetch its own data from?

If I can still achieve sharable URLs by keeping the data fetching in the parent *Photos* component, how can I reflect this in a route (which eventually can be shared/linked on social media,emails,etc.)?

Comment: FWIW, I think I was grappling with similar concerns, and ended up making some mistakes (I don't have an answer, this is just FYI): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40066286/how-to-avoid-taking-off-the-child-prop-in-a-container-on-a-route